Mixed integer programming formulation of point cover with specified miscover rate?
Imagine a set of $N$ points in $R^m$ labeled $y_{+}$ or $y_{-}$. The task is to pick a corner of $m$ dimensional box $(x_1,x_2,...x_m)$ such that rectangle $(-\infty,-\infty,...,-\infty)$ to $(x_1,x_2,...x_m)$ covers the maximum number of $y_{+}$ points, while the number of covered $y_{-}$ points is $\leq T$, where $T$ is some specified integer number.
Is there a way to formulate this problem as a mixed integer programming problem or any other algorithmic way to solve it?

Slight change in notation: I will refer to $y^+_i \in \mathbb{R}^m$ as the $i$-th desired point and $y^-_i\in \mathbb{R}^m$ as the $i$-th undesired point.
Introduce binary variables $z^+_i$ and $z^-_i$ taking value 1 if and only if the hyperrectangle contains the corresponding $y$ point. The objective is to maximize $\sum_i z^+_i$ and the coverage limit is $\sum_i z^-_i \le T.$
Defining $z^+_i$ is easy. We just need the constraints $$y^+_{ij} \le x_j + M(1-z^+_i)\quad \forall i, j$$ where $M$ is a sufficiently large positive constant. To define $z^-_i,$ we need another set of binary variables $w_{ij}$ and a small positive constant $\epsilon.$ The corresponding constraints are $$y^-_{ij} \ge x_j + \epsilon - M(1-w_{ij})\quad \forall i,j$$ and $$z^-_i \ge 1 - \sum_j w_{ij}\quad \forall i.$$
The $\epsilon$ term is necessary because strict inequalities cannot be used in math programming models.

Looks promising, I will try this as soon as possible. What is this technique you used? Can you dive into a little bit more details about where inequalities came from?

The big-M inequalities are a standard approach to encoding an implication of the form "binary variable = true implies inequality holds". You will find lots of examples of it on Operations Research Stack Exchange.

I checked this formulation, and it indeed solves the problem. I will be accepting your answer as the solution. About the big-M method: it's fine and known to me, the question is, for example, in your first inequality, why are you modelling the $z^+i$ binary variable from an implication? Why not, for example, equilvalence? What if $z^+i$ = 0? Then the inequality always holds, but why wouldn't you want $y^+{ij}>x_j$ in this case? Also where do $w{ij}$ come from? What is their purpose? If you could dive into a bit more details, that would help future readers.

The reason for modeling implication rather than equivalence is to reduce the size of the model. Since you are maximizing the sum of the $z^+$ variables, the solver will never set one of them to 0 when the corresponding $y^+$ point is actually covered. With $z^-$ it's a bit more subtle. Theoretically the solver could set the $z^-$ variable to 1 even when the $y^-$ point is uncovered, but it would be harmless in terms of the solution quality.

The $w$ variables are necessary because the definition of $z^-$ involves a disjunction: if any one component of the $y^-$ point is outside the box, the $z^-$ variable is 0. The definition of $z^+$ involved a conjunction (all components must be in the box), so no auxiliary variables were needed there.

Excellent answer my good sir. This resolves all my questions.
